# Execute SQL task while importing Excel file to SQL server

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I'm using SSIS to import data from an Excel spreadsheet into a SQL database. I have this working. I used a data flow task to Import from Excel then Move to OLE DB destination.

However, I'd like to use a SQL query to add a column with the current date (i.e. date imported to database) before moving it. The only place I can execute a SQL task is in the control flow window and I'm unsure where to put it. If I run the SQL before the data flow task, there won't be an Excel file to work on, but if I run the SQL after the data flow task, the file will already be imported to the database.

At what point in the flow should I insert the SQL task? Or should I use two data flow tasks and run the SQL task between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution. I left the SSIS solution unchanged and instead used a trigger in the SQL Server to insert the current date when the table in question is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a separate SQL Task, you could use a Derived Column to add the date column inside your existing Data Flow.

If you go this route, you'll end up with something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9512395/117424.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways -

1) You can add derived column in SSIS data flow task

2) You can assign default value as getdate() to your date column instead of trigger.