# SSIS Mapping and Transformation

Tags: sql, ssis, mapping, etl

I'm new to building SSIS packages, in fact this is my first package. I need to pull data from one DB view on Azure managed instance to an SQL on prem. I have built out the data flow and all. I'm moving data from a database view into a another database table but the destination table has a column that the source doesn't have hence my destination mapping view looks like  (See attached image) How do I fix this or what are my options?

[image]

Comment: This isn't really related to the SQL _language_. Replace the <sql> tag with a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: You don't have to have all the columns mapped up, unless the destination table does not allow null for them columns.

Answer (score 1):

If this columns needs to stay empty in the source and you don't have it in source your best and only option is leave it like this. It basically needs to ignore it so no information will be fed. That will work.

In case you need information as current date you can add derivied column box in between your source and destination in your Data Flow where you can add current date or more columns that come from variable for example.

Answer (score 0):

Its self explanatory that ignore(optional) means mapping for those columns can be ignored and if you want columns to be mapped with any calculated column you can do it by using derived column SSIS component   [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9512395/7130689)

As per your use case,try to use OLD DB component instead of ADO.NET component
to optimize performance for a relatively large data set